# Deleting a post on Stack Overflow

Tags: support

After deleting a post on Stack Overflow, why am I still able to see it? It is just flagged as Deleted. Will that post be visible to others, or just to me? Also, does that mean that the post will be deleted after certain period of time, or there is some other reason why it’s still there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only you, moderators and users having 10k rep or more can see the post.

But nobody can search for it any more. So one can only view it if he still got the link to it.

Posts do normally not get hard-deleted at all.

Comment: So if they wanted to upvote or downvote can they do that to a deleted post?

Comment: No, it is frozen when deleted. You can edit it or flag it for undeletion. But that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

Posts that are deleted aren't actually deleted. They are just hidden. They can even be undeleted if enough people vote to undelete them. (There are [privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) to see and delete/undelete vote on questions and answers.)

Posts that are deleted are editable. You can delete comments on them. You can't vote on the question or answer though.